# How do I pass a parameter to a Controller which contains a dot?

Tags: c#, razor, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net-apicontroller

I am validating using jQuery:

```
$el.rules("add", {
    remote: {
        url: `/api/distributors/KeywordExists`,
        type: "post",
        data: {
            id: @Model.Distributor.DistributorId
        }
    }
});
```

The `$el` is an input element generated by Razor Pages from a `string[]`, so it is rendered like this:
`<input class="form-control keyword" type="text" id="Distributor_Keywords_0_" name="Distributor.Keywords[0]" >`

After that there is the next element in the `string[]`:
`<input class="form-control keyword" type="text" id="Distributor_Keywords_1_" name="Distributor.Keywords[1]" >` etc.

In order to validate, the `rules` say to check `/api/distributors/KeywordExists` . This method looks like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET","POST"), Route("KeywordExists")]
public JsonResult KeywordExists(long id, string keyword)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
    {
        var match = CheckDbIfKeywordIsMatch();
        if (match is not null)
        {
            return new JsonResult(!match.Exists) ;
        }
    }

    return new JsonResult(true);
}
```

The actual API works perfectly, the problem is that it only works when the parameters are `id` and `keyword` However the jQuery validation sends the following Form Data in its payload:

1. **Distributor.Keywords[0]:**

   Amazon
2. **id:**

   1

Therefore, the URL is `Distributor.Keywords%5B0%5D=Amazon&id=1`

which the Controller does not recognize.

If I could write `KeywordExists(long id, string Distributor.Keyword*)` that would catch the params being sent but obviously I can't.

I have tried adding [Bind] attributes to no avail

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use custom model binding to bind `Distributor.Keywords[x]` with `keyword`,here is a demo:

url:

```
https://localhost:xxxx/A/KeywordExists?Distributor.Keywords%5B0%5D=Amazon&id=1
```

custom model binder:

```
public class CustomBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }
            //get Keyword data with the following code
          
            var data= bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.ToString().Split("&")[0].Split("=")[1];
           


            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(data);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

action:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET","POST"), Route("KeywordExists")]
public JsonResult KeywordExists(long id, [ModelBinder(typeof(CustomBinder))]string keyword)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
    {
        var match = CheckDbIfKeywordIsMatch();
        if (match is not null)
        {
            return new JsonResult(!match.Exists) ;
        }
    }

    return new JsonResult(true);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by //put your logic code of DecimalConverter  here

Comment: I'm sorry,I forgot to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to change the param with a dot. But I solved the problem a different way. I made jQuery validate pass another param called keyword, with the same value as the validated element:

```
$el.rules("add", {
    remote: {
        url: `/api/distributors/KeywordExists`,
        type: "post",
        data: {
            id: () => @Model.Distributor.DistributorId,
            keyword: () => $el.val()
        }
    }
});
```

As these were sent as Form Data in the body, I had to add the following attributes to the controller method otherwise they were null: `KeywordExists([FromForm] long id, [FromForm] string keyword)`
The `Distributor.Keyword[i]` was still being sent in the request body, but as there was also a param called keyword, the framework identified this as the correct method.